# I need to make a post after the page loaded, but I'm using Thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, webbrowser-control

I'm doing a post on a page that works as follows:
Click on a link and opens a text box, then accurately loaded to another post to save the contents of the input text.

Follows the code I'm using.

```
private void btnRobo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // string[] paginasArray = new string[] { txtPaginas.Text };
        string[] paginasArray = txtPaginas.Text.Split('\n');

        foreach (string s in paginasArray)
        {
            //  webBrowser1.Navigate(s);
            if (s.Trim() != "")
                runBrowserThread(new Uri(s));
        }

    }


        private void runBrowserThread(Uri url)
    {
        var th = new Thread(() =>
        {
            var br = new WebBrowser();
            br.DocumentCompleted += browser_DocumentCompleted;
            br.Navigate(url);
            Application.Run();
        });
        th.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        th.Start();
    }

    void browser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        var br = sender as WebBrowser;
        if (br.Url == e.Url)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Natigated to {0}", e.Url);
            webBrowser1.Navigate(e.Url);
            //ExecutaPostagem();
            HtmlElementCollection elements = br.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");


            foreach (HtmlElement currentElement in elements)
            {

                if ((currentElement.GetAttribute("type") == "submit") && (currentElement.Name == "view_post"))
                {
                    string postagem = txtPublicacao.Text;
                    HtmlElement elea = br.Document.GetElementById("u_0_0");
                    if (elea != null) elea.SetAttribute("value", postagem);
                    currentElement.InvokeMember("click");
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    fullyLoaded = false;
                }


            }


            Application.ExitThread();   // Stops the thread
        }
    }
```

After the page was loaded by the **browser_DocumentCompleted** need to run the code below, but how will I run the code if I am using thread and I'm no longer using the event **browser_DocumentCompleted**

```
var links = br.Document.GetElementsByTagName("A");
            // var links = webBrowser1.Document.All;
            foreach (HtmlElement link in links)
            {
                // if (link.InnerText != null)
                if ((link.InnerText != null) && (link.InnerText.Contains("comentários")))
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    MessageBox.Show(link.InnerText.ToString()); //.Contains("comentários").ToString());
                    //MessageBox.Show(link.GetAttribute("InnerText")); 
                    // MessageBox.Show(link.GetAttribute("className"));
                    link.InvokeMember("click");
                    break;
                }

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use WebClient or Threads at all.
Instead use http://restsharp.org/ to make the call to your website. Restsharp is super easy to work with.

And instead of using Threads use async/await (restsharp also supports this) to modify the UI later.